# Cannot connect to mongo server (amd64) v4.2 from ubuntu (arm64) mongoclient v4.0

Tags: arm, mongodb

The mongod that i am using is in ubuntu
[image: Mongo server up]

The mongo server version is **v4.2.8** and is in amd64 ubuntu 16.04.

Note: PortBinding is already set to 0.0.0.0

When I connect it from my PC. The connection is successful. I connect from mongo client **v4.2.3**

When I connect from another VPS with arm64 Ubuntu 16.04 with mongo client **v4.0.20**. It says `Connection Timed Out`.

[image: Mongo connection fail]

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Is the MongoDB instance running on your PC or a different server?

Comment: On another remote VPS

Comment: Socket timeouts are usually a symptom of a firewall somewhere in between.  Did you whitelist your PC's IP on the Mongo DB server and maybe didn't do so for the other VPS?

Comment: I found the solution. It was actually AWS ec2 blocking egress on 27017. Thank you for your comment.